# Do transactions on the Kovan test network consume any gas?

Tags: ethereum

I'm on the Kovan test network.

When I transfer 1ETH from account #1 to account #2 I see the following after the transaction is processed:

```
Provided 21,000 gas (20,000M/ETH) for a total transaction value of 1.00042 ETH
```

Who pays for the gas? I thought it would be account #1 and so I expected to the see the balance down by 1.00042ETH but it is only down by 1ETH.

In terms of gas consumption and payments how is the Kovan network different from the main network?

Answer (score 1):

> Do transactions on the Kovan test network consume any gas?

Yes they do, and currently in all Ethereum implementations, the transaction sender pays the fee.

Have you checked your address(es) at https://kovan.etherscan.io ? Maybe the transaction wasn't mined. If it was, your balance must have dropped by 1.00042ETH. However, if address #2 is a contract, then your transaction might have triggered an internal transaction that pays you back Ethers. If you share your address, it would be easier to be sure what's going on.